# What's the right approach to generate multiple CSS bundles and import only the necessary ones on runtime?

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, sass

My team and I are currently working on a multi template / multi skin app. This means there is a base style and multiple style overwrites or custom styles. We use Sass.

There's basically a new template every month, this means that the styles files grow in size and in number.

What we currently do is to generate a single CSS bundle using Webpack. The app (React) imports that bundle. Only some styles are applied depending on which template we are using. It is not possible to switch from one template to the other during run time. The template to be used is determined server side using an identifier. We just basically use that identifier as the class of the root element so only the necessary styles are applied to it and its children.

The approach has worked for us so far cause there are still just a few templates. But we know this will impact the load times potentially if more and more styles are created.

We've thought about generating multiple bundles during build time but we will still need to get only THE ONE we need during run time. This way we would avoid bringing a big bundle from the server.

I would like to hear some suggestions and what would be a good approach to accomplish this.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are trying to approach more to adaptive templating / styling rather than responsive?

Comment: exactly. I just want to import the styles I need, rather than a bunch of stuff I don't need in order to decrease load times